# Error deploying neo4j cluster on Kubernetes namespace

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, neo4j

I am trying to install neo4j on kubernetes using Helm to a separate namespace and cluster startup is failing with the below error. But the same install into default namespace is working fine. Anyone else experienced same issue?

```
2018-01-04 09:11:11.636+0000 INFO  Discovering cluster with initial members: [mynamespace-neo4j.default.svc.cluster.local:5000]
2018-01-04 09:11:11.637+0000 INFO  Attempting to connect to the other cluster members before continuing...
2018-01-04 09:16:44.756+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@42698b5f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Failed to join a cluster with members {clusterId=null, bootstrappable=false, coreMembers={}}. Another member should have published a clusterId but none was detected. Please restart the cluster.". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@42698b5f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Failed to join a cluster with members {clusterId=null, bootstrappable=false, coreMembers={}}. Another member should have published a clusterId but none was detected. Please restart the cluster.".
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@42698b5f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Failed to join a cluster with members {clusterId=null, bootstrappable=false, coreMembers={}}. Another member should have published a clusterId but none was detected. Please restart the cluster.".
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:215)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:80)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@42698b5f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Failed to join a cluster with members {clusterId=null, bootstrappable=false, coreMembers={}}. Another member should have published a clusterId but none was detected. Please restart the cluster.".
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by upgrading the chart to latest.